# Upload sql database to remote server using Terminal on Mac?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a large local SQL database. When I try to upload the file to the remote database I get a message saying the file is too large.

My hosting provider told me I need to upload the SQL database to remote server using Terminal on Mac.

I need to know the Terminal commands to connect and upload the file.

Comment: which database software?

Comment: phpMyAdmin 2.9.0.
I tried: mysql -u user -p database.
But I get the message "-bash: mysql: command not found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install the mysql client for Mac, I don't know the specifics on how that is done, sorry.

Then if the mysql client works the same way as on linux, the dump command would be something like:

```
mysqldump -u user -p databasename > dump.sql
```

Then using SCP or a graphical sftp software, transfer the file to the remote server:

```
scp dump.sql user@remotehost.ip:
```

Then use the mysql client there to import the dump.sql with:

```
mysql -u user -p databasename < dump.sql
```

You might need to create an empty database with the desired name before you import the dump.

Comment: I now know that the problem is that I have not installed mysql in local. But I do have installed MAMP and it include mysql. Don't know if I have to install mysql in other way than trough MAMP ??¿¿

Comment: MAMP MySQL via Command line: http://www.aschroder.com/2009/03/how-to-use-the-mamp-mysql-command-line-client-in-a-terminal/

Comment: I saw the page you linked me but it show how to run commands on local machine. Once I am in mysql> can I connect to a remote database. How?

Comment: You must SSH into the remote server to run the mysql import command I listed there. As my answer says, first you run the two local commands, and then SSH into the remote machine to run the last command.

Comment: ok I see, I'll try that.